# How to convert array of objects to given format using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to format an array of data using JavaScript. I am using the following data:

```
var response = [{
      day_id:1,
      day_name:"Monday",
      subcat_id:"2",
      cat_id:"1",
      comment:"hii"
}, {
      day_id:1,
      day_name:"Monday",
      subcat_id:"1",
      cat_id:"2",
      comment:"hello"
}
 {
      day_id:2,
      day_name:"Tuesday",
      subcat_id:"3",
      cat_id:"2",
      comment:"hii"
}]
```

... and I need to convert it to the following format

```
var responseNew = {
      data: [{
        day_name: "Monday",
        day_id:1
        answers:[{
          cat_id:1,
          subcat_id:1,
          comment:'hii'
        },{
          cat_id:1,
          subcat_id:2,
          comment:'hello'
        }]
      }, {
        day_name: "Tuesday",
        day_id:2
        answers:[{
          cat_id:3,
          subcat_id:2,
          comment:'hello'
        }]
      }, {
        day_name: "Wednesday"
         day_id:3
      }, {
        day_name: "Thursday"
         day_id:4
      }, {
        day_name: "Friday"
         day_id:5
      }, {
        day_name: "Saturday",
         day_id:6
      }, {
        day_name: "Sunday"
         day_id:7
      }]
    };
```

I want to convert my first array into the second format. One condition is if other day_id is not present it simply sets the day name and day id in static as given above.

Comment: How about showing us what you have tried? You provided no code, just input and expected output. SO isn't a "code it for me" site, it's a place to get help. If you have a specific problem we'd be glad to help, but we're not going to write the algorithm for you from scratch.

Comment: Can you please help me to do this./

Comment: i had done somethig but that gone wrong thats why i need help.

Comment: So supply the "wrong" code and we'll help you improve it. We're not going to write it for you.

Comment: FYI, I should also mention, neither of the things you provided are JSON. They are JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 1):

Using underscore to group by day_id then use map to render your espected object

```js
  var response = [{
    day_id: 1,
    day_name: "Monday",
    subcat_id: "2",
    cat_id: "1",
    comment: "hii"
  }, {
    day_id: 1,
    day_name: "Monday",
    subcat_id: "1",
    cat_id: "2",
    comment: "hello"
  }, {
    day_id: 2,
    day_name: "Tuesday",
    subcat_id: "3",
    cat_id: "2",
    comment: "hii"
  }];


  var responseNew = _.chain(response)
    .groupBy("day_id")
    .map(function(obj) {
      return {
        day_name: obj[0].day_name,
        day_id: obj[0].day_id,
        answers: obj.map(function(o) {
          return {
            cat_id: o.cat_id,
            subcat_id: o.subcat_id,
            comment: o.comment
          }
        })
      };
    });
console.log(responseNew);

$("#myPre").html(JSON.stringify(responseNew, null, 4));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="myPre"></pre>
```